# How to call a function with positional-only parameters given an arguments dictionary?

Tags: python, signature, pep570

Previously I've used `Signature.bind(argument_dict)` to turn argument dictionary into `BoundArguments` object that has `.args` and `.kwargs` that can be passed to a function.

```py
def foo(a: str, b: str, c: str): ...
    
argument_dict= {"a": "A", "c": "C", "b": "B"}

import inspect
sig = inspect.signature(foo)

bound_arguments = sig.bind(**argument_dict)
foo(*bound_arguments.args, **bound_arguments.kwargs)
```

But this does not seem to be possible when the function has positional-only parameters.

```py
def foo(a: str, /, b: str, *, c: str): ...
    
import inspect
sig = inspect.signature(foo)

argument_dict= {"a": "A", "b": "B", "c": "C"}
bound_arguments = sig.bind(**argument_dict) # Error: "a" is positional-only
```

How do I programmatically call the function in this case?

Is these a native way to construct `BoundArguments` from an argument dictionary?

Answer (score 3):

I could only find something like this, consuming the positional only parameters from the dict:

```
pos_only = [k for k, v in sig.parameters.items() if v.kind is inspect.Parameter.POSITIONAL_ONLY]
positionals = [argument_dict.pop(k) for k in pos_only]
bound_arguments = sig.bind(*positionals, **argument_dict)
```